# Probability that iid uniform random variables equal the natural numbers

Tags: probability-theory

I have random variables $X_1 , X_2 \ldots $ that $X_n\sim \text{Unif}\{ 1, \ldots , n\}$, and I want to calculate

$$\Bbb P ( \{ X_1 , X_2 , \ldots \} = \Bbb N )$$

My intuition is that this means each $X_n = n$, which occurs with probability $\frac 1 n$.

Does this seem correct?

Comment: In fact this is is not the same question as the linked one.

Comment: Please compare the linked question carefully! THIS IS NOT A DUPLICATE!

Answer (score 0):

Not quite. Just because we have $\{X_1,X_2,\dots\}=\mathbb{N}$, this does not necessarily imply that $X_1=1$, $X_2=2$, and so on. Rather, all we know is that the set of all $X_n$'s includes every natural number. For instance, we could have
$$(X_1,X_2,X_3,X_4,X_5,X_6,...)=(1,1,2,2,3,3,...).$$
There are infinitely many possible sequences. Moreover, the probability of any particular sequence of $(X_1,X_2,X_3,...)$ is $\frac{1}{2}\cdot\frac{1}{2}\cdot\frac{1}{3}\cdots =0$. So we'll have to reason differently.

Notice that $\{X_1,X_2,\dots\}=\mathbb{N}$ if and only if for every $n \in \mathbb{N}$, we have $n \in \{X_1,X_2,\dots\}$. Therefore we have $\{X_1,X_2,\dots\}\neq \mathbb{N}$ if and only if there exists $n \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $n \notin\{X_1,X_2,\dots\}$. So we can write
$$\{\{X_1,X_2,\dots\}\neq\mathbb{N}\} = \bigcup_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \{n \notin \{X_1,X_2,\dots\}\}.$$
We can use a union bound to write
$$P(\{X_1,X_2,\dots\}\neq \mathbb{N}) \leq \sum_{n=1}^\infty P(n \notin \{X_1,X_2,\dots\}).$$
The advantage of this is that the event $\{n \notin\{X_1,X_2,\dots\}\}$ implies $X_1 \neq n$, $X_2 \neq n$, $X_3 \neq n$, and so on. This is something we can actually calculate the probability of, assuming the $X_i$ are independent.

You should find that all of these probabilities are zero, so $P(\{X_1,X_2,\dots\}=\mathbb{N})=1$.

Comment: Why is the probability zero for each n?

Comment: @Bindiya12 Because we are not calculating a probability for *each* $n$, rather for *all* $n$. So we have an infinite product of terms all less than 1, which goes to 0.

Comment: This reasoning is not sufficient. See my answer.

Comment: @Falrach This argument is fine. You can bound the infinite product from above and show it's $0$

Comment: @ablmf The answer is fine. I was arguing about the comment. (I hope I did not misunderstand you?). There is a last step missing in the answer (to show that the product is $0$)

Comment: @Falrach I see. Yeah the comment is insufficient. I agree.

Comment: @Falrach I see my comment is a little unclear. I did not mean to suggest that every such product goes to 0, but this one does. The calculation is very straightforward and does not require Borel-Cantelli. Indeed 
$$P(X_n \neq n,X_{n+1}\neq n,X_{n+1}\neq n,...)= \frac{n-1}{n}\cdot \frac{n}{n+1}\cdot \frac{n+1}{n+2}\cdots = \lim_{N \to \infty} \frac{n-1}{N} = 0$$.

Comment: Yes this is much easier.

Answer (score 0):

Since I am not confident with the reasoning inthe comment of the other answer I will give another last argumentation step.

Indeed, we can give the bound bound
$$\Bbb P(\{X_1,X_2,\dots\}\neq \mathbb{N}) \leq \sum_{n=1}^\infty \Bbb P(n \notin \{X_1,X_2,\dots\})$$
Now indeed
$$\Bbb P(n \notin \{X_1,X_2,\dots\}) = \Bbb P(X_1 \neq n , X_2 \neq n , \ldots) = \Bbb P(X_{n} \neq n , X_{n+1} \neq n , \ldots)$$
which is indeed an infinite product. But the fact that all factors are less thatn $1$ is not sufficient to conclude that that this product is zero. For example
$\prod_{k=1}^\infty e^{-\frac 1 {k^2}} = e^{-\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac 1 {k^2}} = e^{- \frac{\pi^2}{6}}  > 0$. Therefore we need an additional argument. Now note that
$$\sum_{k=n}^\infty \Bbb P (X_k = n) = \sum_{k=n}^\infty \frac 1 k = \infty$$
The Borel-Cantelli lemma implies that
$$\Bbb P ( X_k = n \text{ for infinitely many } k \geq n) = 1$$
In particular we get $$\Bbb P ( X_k = n \text{ for at least one } k \geq n) = 1$$
which shows that $$\Bbb P(X_{n} \neq n , X_{n+1} \neq n , \ldots) =  0$$
All in all $\Bbb P(\{X_1,X_2,\dots\}\neq \mathbb{N}) = 0$.